# How to draw a function on a scatter plot in ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I want to plot a function -- e.g. a line-- inside a scatterplot. I have composed code that do both separately but how I can combine them?  My experimentations returned error messages.

My code is the following:

```
library(ROSE)
data(hacide)
train <- hacide.train
```

## Scatter plot

```
ggplot(train, aes(x1, x2, colour = cls)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

## Line

```
db <- function(x, beta1, beta2, alpha){-alpha/beta2 - x * beta1/beta2}

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x = x))  +
  stat_function(fun = db, args = list(-1.642354, -1.596056, -6.004609), colour = "blue" , size = 2)
```

[image]

But how to superimpose / combine the line with the scatter plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x = x))  +
  stat_function(fun = db, args = list(-1.642354, -1.596056, -6.004609), colour = "blue" , size = 2)+
  geom_point(data = train, aes(x1, x2, colour = cls),  size = 3, alpha = 0.4)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way to do this is just add the function to the original plot. The graphs in `ggplot2` are constructed in layers, meaning you can always add more layers while you construct your graphs.

For your code you could either do:

```
library(ROSE)
data(hacide)
train <- hacide.train

db <- function(x, beta1, beta2, alpha){-alpha/beta2 - x * beta1/beta2}

ggplot(train, aes(x1, x2, colour = cls)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_function(fun = db, args = list(-1.642354, -1.596056, -6.004609),
  colour = "blue" , size = 2)
```

or add it to the existing plot:

```
library(ROSE)
data(hacide)
train <- hacide.train

plot = ggplot(train, aes(x1, x2, colour = cls)) +
       geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.4)

db <- function(x, beta1, beta2, alpha){-alpha/beta2 - x * beta1/beta2}

plot + stat_function(fun = db, args = list(-1.642354, -1.596056, -6.004609),
colour = "blue" , size = 2)
```